# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS xorg-dev repos busted is there work around?

Tags: apt, package-management, xorg, dependencies

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with all updates applied. Running in Oracle VirtualBox VM.

ubuntu-bug is completely busted. When I tried to report it took me to the Web site and demanded I enter a package name, would not allow "I don't know" button to be checked. When trying to search for a package there were no packages in the list. Nice, very nice.

The repos for 20.04 LTS have xorg-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev completely broken at least as far as dependencies are concerned. Many many of the dependencies fail just like this:

```
developer@a-developer-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libfontenc-dev zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The needed -dev package is forced to depend on a version that is no longer the one the repos will try to install.

```
developer@a-developer-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl-dev : Depends: libgl1 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
             Depends: libglx-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Right now the official repo is in such a state nobody can install xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev. One cannot even report bugs.

**Is there a work around for getting xorg-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev installed with all development dependencies?**

We chose Ubuntu 20.04 LTS because the LTS releases aren't supposed to have things like this in the repos.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.3) but 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.3)
 libmount-dev : Depends: libmount1 (= 2.34-0.1ubuntu9) but 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libblkid-dev but it is not going to be installed
 uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.34-0.1ubuntu9) but 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I must have been caught up in some kind of push. Seems to be fixed now.

Comment: No, your other question didn't answer it. The default repos were in place. I simply tried a few hours later and it worked. Either Canonical was pushing updates out or the mirrors were out of sync. You should NOT have closed this question.